# GRUB stopped displaying correctly

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, dualboot

I have a Kubuntu and Windows dual boot setup. Initially all was fine, but recently GRUB stopped rendering correctly, displaying only a black screen on boot. I can still press enter to boot to Kubuntu, or press the down arrow key twice and then enter to boot to Windows, but it'd be nice to fix it and prevent headaches in the future. Any idea what I can try?

Thank you for your time.

---

EDIT:

As an answer suggested I tried `boot-repair`, however that didn't appear to do much - it seemed to have reinstalled GRUB, but the problem persists.

Any further suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you've [Grub Customizer](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-and-use-grub-customizer-on-ubuntu/) to change choices, boot order or appearance, a font or background image that cannot be displayed correctly could cause that issue. In that case, use Grub Customizer to select default font and background.

If that is not the case, then try [Boot Repair](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-repair-the-grub2-boot-loader-on-linux/) to fix the issue. BTW, when grub2 completely fails to load Linux, I've used a Linux live USB drive to download Boot Repair and to fix the issue... no need to actually (re)install Linux.

Comment: I didn't modify GRUB in any way, and the device is booting both Linux and Windows just fine, its just that the monitor is black when it boots. Quick question on ```boot-repair```, do I actually need to boot from a USB drive? Linux still boots fine. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to run Boot Repair from a mounted drive with the OS, i.e. Kubuntu, but if you can't, then try a USB.

Comment: I see, will check back later. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, I tried `boot-repair` with the recommended repairs, but it seems like it hasn't changed much, all I saw was it seems to have reinstalled GRUB, but that's about it, and the boot menu is still invisible... Any other ideas?